# Extract wav file from video file

Tags: c#, winforms, video, audio

I am developing an application in which I need to extract the audio from a video. The audio needs to be extracted in .wav format but I do not have a problem with the video format. Any format will do, as long as I can extract the audio in a wav file.

Currently I am using Windows Media Player COM control in a windows form to play the videos, but any other embedded player will do as well.

Any suggestions on how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a link](http://www.videohelp.com/forum/archive/how-to-extract-to-wav-from-avi-using-graphedit-t239907.html) on how to extract audio using GraphEdit, GraphEdit is an front end UI for the [DirectShow API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783323.aspx) so everything it can do you can do with API.
You can use the [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) liberty which wraps the DirectShow API for the managed world.

Comment: In this case should I provide the users with the DirectX libraries as well in the installer?

Comment: DirectShow comes built in with XP and up.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this with C#, take a look at [NAudio library](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio). It can analyze the audio format (like FFMpeg) and also provide the audio stream. Here's [one example](https://github.com/tompaana/hls-transcription-sample).

Snippet from the sample:

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.IO;

...

// contentAsByteArray consists of video bytes
MemoryStream contentAsMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(contentAsByteArray);

using (WaveStream pcmStream =
    WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(
        new StreamMediaFoundationReader(contentAsMemoryStream)))
{
    WaveStream blockAlignReductionStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(pcmStream);

    // Do something with the wave stream
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19283625)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are absolutely right. I will try to do as you advised in the future. Here the answer would be quite lengthy given the fairly broad topic and frankly I don't know where to start. NAudio library is essential to my solution.

Comment: Added a snippet

Comment: Hey thanks! I asked that question 9 years ago and I used the solution provided in the accepted answer I think. Your solution seems quite good as well, unfortunately I cannot really test it any more. :)

Comment: @NikosSteiakakis I had to solve this problem last week and that's how I found your question. Since the topic is still relevant and lacked a satisfying answer (for my use-case) I decided to provide mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to use ffmpeg for this kinda thing...

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking something more in a .dll form, but an executable will do the trick if I don't find anything more suitable.

Comment: There's no shame in shelling out to an exe! ;) Yes, i know where you're coming from. Depends how professional you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy with FFMPEG!  I routinely do this to grab audio out of downloaded youtube videos, convert music downlaods to WAV for editing, etc etc. It should work for any file extension:

ffmpeg -i source-of-any-file-extension.avi -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 768000 -f wav target-filename.wav