# Python extract wav from video file

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, gstreamer

Related:

[How to extract audio from a video file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216450/how-to-extract-audio-from-a-video-file-using-python)

[Extract audio from video as wav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117488/extract-audio-from-video-as-wav)

[How to rip the audio from a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506651/how-to-rip-the-audio-from-a-video)

My question is how could I extract wav audio track from video file, say `video.avi`? 
I read many articles and everywhere people suggest to use (from Python) `ffmpeg` as a subprocess (because there are no reliable python bindings to ffmpeg - the only hope was `PyFFmpeg` but i found it is unmaintaned now).  I don't know if it is right solution and i am looking for good one.
I looked to gstreamer and found it nice but unable to satisfy my needs -- the only way I found to accomplish this from command line looks like

```
 gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=file://`pwd`/ex.mp4  audio-sink='identity single-segment=true ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)16000, channels=(int)1 ! wavenc !  filesink location=foo.wav’
```

But it is not efficient because i need to wait ages while playing video and simultaneously  writing to wav file.

`ffmpeg` is much better:

```
avconv  -i foo.mp4  -ab 160k -ac 1 -ar 16000 -vn ffaudio.wav
```

But i am unable to launch it from python (not as a command line subprocess). Could you please point me out pros and cons of launching ffmpeg from python as a command line utility ? (I mean using python `multiprocessing` module or something similar).

**And second question.**

What is simple way to cut long wav file into pieces so that i don't break any words ? i mean pieces of 10-20 sec length with start and end during the pause in sentences/words ?

i know how to break them on arbitrary pieces:

```
import wave


win= wave.open('ffaudio.wav', 'rb')
wout= wave.open('ffsegment.wav', 'wb')

t0, t1= 2418, 2421 # cut audio between 2413, 2422 seconds
s0, s1= int(t0*win.getframerate()), int(t1*win.getframerate())
win.readframes(s0) # discard
frames= win.readframes(s1-s0)

wout.setparams(win.getparams())
wout.writeframes(frames)

win.close()
wout.close()
```

Comment: You mention `ffmpeg`, but you're using `avconv`.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv. They are different projects and substitution one for another. `avconv` if fork of `ffmpeg` which was done to distance themselves from `FFmpeg project`.

Comment: If you launch ffmeg  in ubuntu you will see message like this: `The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility and will be removed in a future release. It has been deprecated in the Libav project to allow for incompatible command line syntax improvements in its replacement called avconv. Please use avconv instead.`

Comment: Explore the moviepy library as suggested here [by Daweo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55081534/10944913)

Answer (score 62):

It is a very easy Task using **ffmpeg** with **python** subprocess and there is a reason why people are pointing to this solution as a good solution.

This is the basic command extracting audio from a given video File:

> ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ab 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn audio.wav

The Python Code is just wrapping this command:

```
import subprocess

command = "ffmpeg -i C:/test.mp4 -ab 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn audio.wav"

subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

You have to make sure that ffmpeg is a known task, so in your system environment variables, under path, the path to ffmpeg.exe should be listed, or you can just use the full path to the exe in your python code.

Comment: Thank you very mach. But I am not new to Python and know how to accomplish this with `subprocess` or `multiprocessing`  module. I was asking about possible disadvantages of this approach. Except unknown path to `ffmpeg`/`aconv` in a system (which i could easily find by myself) i know nothing of them. So i have asked this question in a hope that somebody will point me out another disadvantages of this approach.

Comment: Honestly, if you are trying to use free available libraries, i don't think that you will find something better and easier to use then ffmpeg.

Comment: Do we have to specify absolute path toward `videofile` and `audiofile` in this code, if our `.py` file is located at different place?

Comment: Wherever u launched the python session from is the base path. I would suggest using absolute path, at one point if u are debugging, u could copy paste the command and run it in shell.

Comment: nice, the answer also works for webm as source file!

Comment: where does it save it?

Answer (score 10):

this could be better and easier to use than ffmpeg, it's called python-video converter, and can be used to extract the audio from video, https://github.com/senko/python-video-converter , it could be used in conjunction with mpg123, as follows

```
    from converter import Converter
    import os
    c = Converter()
    clip = 'clip.avi'
    conv = c.convert(clip, 'audio.mp3', {'format':'mp3','audio':{'codec': 'mp3','bitrate':'22050','channels':1}})
    for timecode in conv:
        pass    
    os.system("mpg123 -w audio.wav audio.mp3")
```

the converter module extracts the audio from the video and saves it as an mp3 file, while mpg123 converts the mp3 file to mp4,

a different solution is as follows:
using moviepy module in python https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy

```
    import moviepy.editor as mp
    clip = mp.VideoFileClip("video.avi").subclip(0,20)
    clip.audio.write_audiofile("theaudio.mp3")
```

the numbers within the subclip function specify start and end of audio, in seconds. you can then use mpg123 to change the audio to any other format

Answer (score 9):

Audio clips can be created from an audio file or from the soundtrack of a video file

```
from moviepy.editor import *
audioclip = AudioFileClip("some_audiofile.mp3")
audioclip = AudioFileClip("some_video.avi")
```

https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/audioclips.html

Answer (score 1):

or example extract mp3 from

```
import os

VIDEOS_PATH = '/Users/****/videos'
VIDEOS_EXTENSION = '.webm'  # for example
AUDIO_EXT = 'wav'

EXTRACT_VIDEO_COMMAND = ('ffmpeg -i "{from_video_path}" '
                         '-f {audio_ext} -ab 192000 '
                         '-vn "{to_audio_path}"')

os.chdir(VIDEOS_PATH)
files = os.listdir(VIDEOS_PATH)
for f in files:
    if not f.endswith(VIDEOS_EXTENSION):
        continue

    audio_file_name = '{}.{}'.format(f, AUDIO_EXT)
    command = EXTRACT_VIDEO_COMMAND.format(
        from_video_path=f, audio_ext=AUDIO_EXT, to_audio_path=audio_file_name,
    )
    os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using librosa and soundfile**
*You can use packages like librosa and soundfile and use following code to extract audio from video file*

```
import librosa
import soundfile as sf
def extract_audio_from_video(video_path,audio_save_path):
   audio , sr = librosa.load(video_path)
   sf.write(audio_path,audio,sr)
extract_audio_from_video("video.mp4","audio.wav")
```

[librosa](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/index.html)
[soundfile](https://pypi.org/project/soundfile/)