# How to convert mp4 to mp3 using python

Tags: python, audio, mp3

How can I convert a mp4 or mpeg4 file to mp3 using python?

I have looked at several libraries without success.

Comment: Which libraries did you try, and what problems did you have with them?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This sounds like task for [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html). After you install it ([installation howto](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html)) it could be used following way:

```py
import os
from moviepy.editor import *
video = VideoFileClip(os.path.join("path","to","movie.mp4"))
video.audio.write_audiofile(os.path.join("path","to","movie_sound.mp3"))
```

Just replace `"path","to","movie.mp4"` and `"path","to","movie_sound.mp3"` according to your needs.

EDIT: To avoid the KeyError: 'video_fps', do ensure that you aren't inputting any video which does not contain any visual content.

From Comments:

```py
from moviepy.editor import *

def MP4ToMP3(mp4, mp3):
    FILETOCONVERT = AudioFileClip(mp4)
    FILETOCONVERT.write_audiofile(mp3)
    FILETOCONVERT.close()

VIDEO_FILE_PATH = "/Full/File/Path/ToSong.mp4"
AUDIO_FILE_PATH = "/Full/File/Path/ToSong.mp3"

MP4ToMP3(VIDEO_FILE_PATH, AUDIO_FILE_PATH)
# MoviePy - Writing audio in /Full/File/Path/ToSong.mp3
# MoviePy - Done.
```

Comment: give me the error while using VideoFileClip : KeyError: 'video_fps'

Comment: same error.. any solutions to this??

Comment: This worked for me. @YaroslavDukal



`from moviepy.editor import *
def mp4_to_mp3(mp4, mp3):
    mp4_without_frames = AudioFileClip(mp4)
    mp4_without_frames.write_audiofile(mp3)
    mp4_without_frames.close()
# function call
mp4_to_mp3("my_mp4_path.mp4", "audio.mp3")`

Comment: thanks megha your solution is working  at 01/2022

Comment: MoviePy appears to be an unstable and perhaps even abandoned project...  Every time I fix an error, there is another.  Going to look for another solution.

Comment: @Nuclear_Man_D I recently started to search for a solution for it too, did you find a valid one?