# Telegram bot convert mp4 to mp3

Tags: python, audio, video, bots, telegram

i am currently trying to create a telegram bot which can convert mp4 to mp3. The bot needs to receive the videos sent by users and then send back an audio file to them after converting the mp4 to mp3. However, the problem im facing now is that the videos sent by users cant be read by my bot. Do any of you know how to settle this?

```
video =update.message
    
    video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(video)
    audio = video.audio
    audio.write_audiofile("Audio.mp3")
    bot = Bot(
        token="xxx"
    )
    try:
        bot.send_audio(
            chat_id='123',
            audio=open('Audio.mp3', 'rb'),
            timeout=10000,
           
        )
    except:
        update.message.reply_text("Sorry, I couldnt convert this into an audio")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert mp4 to mp3 using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081352/how-to-convert-mp4-to-mp3-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code (thanks to @Daweo [How to convert MP4 to MP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081352/how-to-convert-mp4-to-mp3-using-python):

```
import os
video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(os.path.join("path","to","movie.mp4"))
video.audio.write_audiofile(os.path.join("path","to","movie_sound.mp3"))
```

You simply need to change the file type or to be precise the `path`.