# Extract Waveform From Bytes of MP4 Data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an MP4 video encoded in bytes in memory on a server that has no available storage, only RAM.

Is there a way to get the waveform from that MP4 file without needing to save that file to storage, convert to WAV and then read the WAV file?

Consider the bytes of the MP4 file were read in the following way from a read-only storage attachment that was detached after reading it:

```py
f = open("file.mp4", "rb")
return f.read()
```

Comment: These are at least two different problems. (1) how to extract audio from a mp4 file → see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741116/python-extract-wav-from-video-file); (2) how to pretend working with files on disk when there is no disk.

Comment: Maybe ffmpeg has an API that lets you use it without an external command dealing with files? I don't know.