# C#.NET get audio from a video (MP4, MOV, etc

Tags: .net, audio, video, extract

I need necessary to extract the audio in .WAV format from a video file (MOV , MP4, WMV) code.
C # or VB.NET.

From already thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract wav file from video file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010937/extract-wav-file-from-video-file)

Comment: While it is true the DirectShow library I do not see the code to do what I need is mentioned.
I need your help.